# Find the number of elements of reflexive relation on a set of $n$ elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I do know that $2^{n^{2}-n}$ reflexive relations can be created on $n$-element set.

The problem:

Relation $R$ can be created on $n$-element set $A$.

if such relation $R$ is reflexive, then how many elements should $R$ have?

Comment: R should have atleast n elements.

Comment: A reflexive relation $R$ should have $(x,x) \in R$ for all $x\in A$. Anything else may or may note be in $R$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want for an answer. Is it a proof that $2^{n^2-n}$ is correct or soemthing else?